# Training keras models in a loop: "Tensor is not an element of this graph" when saving model afther calling K.clear_session()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train multiple Keras models in a loop to evaluate different parameters. To avoid memory problems, I call `K.clear_session()`, before each model building.

After adding the `K.clear_session()` call, I started getting this error when saving the second model.

> **raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
>   ValueError: Tensor Tensor("level1/kernel:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 16), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph**.
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/wpy/cnn/srs/train_generators.py", line 286, in 
>       train_models(model_defs)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/wpy/cnn/srs/train_generators.py", line 196, in train_models
>       model.save(file_path)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1090, in save
>       save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 382, in save_model
>       _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 97, in _serialize_model
>       weight_values = K.batch_get_value(symbolic_weights)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2420, in batch_get_value
>       return get_session().run(ops)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
>       self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 471, in **init**
>       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 261, in for_fetch
>       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in **init**
>       self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 370, in 
>       self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 271, in for_fetch
>       return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
>     File "/home/gus/workspaces/venvs/dlcv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 307, in **init**
>       'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e)))
>   **ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("level1/kernel:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 16), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)**

The code basically:

```
while <models to train>:
    K.clear_session()
    model = modeldef.build() # everything that has a tensor goes here and just here
    # create generators from directories

    opt = Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.001 / epochs)
    model.compile(...)
    H = model.fit_generator(...)

    model.save(file_path) # --> here it crashes
```

No matter how deep the network is, a super simple ConvNet like this makes the code fail when saving:

```
class SuperSimpleCNN:
    def __init__(self, img_size, depth):
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.depth = depth

    def build(self):
        init = Input(shape=(self.img_size, self.img_size, self.depth))

        x = Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', name='level1')(init)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)

        out = Convolution2D(self.depth, (5, 5), padding='same', name='output')(x)
        model = Model(init, out)
        return model
```

Looking similar problems, I understand the problem is due to the fact that keras shares a global session, and different graphs from different models can't be mixed.
But I don't understand why using `K.clear_session()` before each model makes the save operation fail when iteration>1. And why the difference between Tensor and Variable.

> <**tf.Variable** 'level1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 16) dtype=float32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a **Tensor**

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I was importing the wrong package:

> from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

instead of

> import keras.backend as K